# Change wording for Close item in review queue

Tags: feature-request, low-quality-posts, wording

On low quality posts queue I faced with a [weird situation](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/879177):

> [image]

<sub>Screenshot was translated by Google.Translate</sub>

Original strings for Close and Delete look very similar:

- This question cannot be fixed and should be closed.
- This post cannot be fixed and should be deleted.

It seems that the wording for Close item should be rephrased to state that fixing is potentially possible but by someone else, not a reviewer. In other words:

- Looks OK - No need to edit
- Edit - I do edit
- Close - Someone does edit
- Delete - Nobody does edit

Comment: *Delete* in this context means to immediately remove the question. *Close* means to immediately close a question pending post-editing.

Comment: Um... Is delete even supposed to be an option here - or is it possible that only mods see it? Unless I'm missing something, non-moderators can't delete *questions* that haven't been closed. Do non mods see this option? If not, I'd recommend we just jettison it entirely (on question reviews) and/or remove and add back the "delete" option under the question itself, which isn't there. The help pages only even talk about deleting answers, so I'm curious if we broke something that should have prevented this from appearing on questions.

Comment: Low quality messages? Test tasks? Story? Why is it that the translations to Russian and then back to English makes it like that?

Comment: @user16217248 that's how translation works (unfortunately). To improve that I have a [FR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391277/339911).

Comment: If I recall correctly, non-mods don't see that option. (@Catija)

Comment: @user16217248 The author's primarily active site is SO in Russian. They used to provide the original Russian screenshots but people complained of them not being understandable so switched to providing machine translations.