# Decline flag option on moderator tool on the question has a wording about "incorrect answer"

Tags: bug, flags, moderator-tools

The following screenshot is automatically translated from Russian by Google:

> [image]

> If it's complete unreadable for you, please, consider voting for the FR: [Add the ability to switch the interface on international sites to English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391277/339911)

[Original English string](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/8085):

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

Decline flag option while processing the flag on the **question** contains wording about incorrect **answer**. Is it expected sentence in tha5 case? Why the answer is mentioned during processing flag for question?

That's how it look naturally on ruSO (it for another flag since the old one is already processed):

> [image]

In the latter case you can even notice (at the right top part) that the question has no answers at all.

Same sentence is (correctly) used while declining the flag on **answer**:

> [image]

Comment: Moderating in Russian seems much more stressful, with all this "anxiety" and "alarms".

Comment: Seriously, why even bother with those awful translations to English? Especially if the issue is Russian-language-exclusive.

Comment: @user3840170 issue isn't Russian-language-exclusive. The translation is correct. Original string is wrong.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Spanish seems much easier, as you just have to deal with "reports" ("reportes"). You don't even have to hear about spam there, as the associated flag is just called "unwanted content" ("contenido no desado").