# Back link on moderator election history page refers to first ever election

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, election, revisions-list

Moderators can see a history of election notice on every election page, e.g. [second (2017) election on ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/2):

> [image]

<sub>If you're a moderator and you have more than one election already, just open the link `{yoursite/election/2}` and find "history" link below the notice.</sub>

But despite the page (election number 2) where you had click the "history" link, you will get "back to election 1" (2015) link at the top of history page:

> [image]

I think the main problem here is that the election notice is shared across all elections on the site.

If you don't understand the screenshots above please consider voting on feature request: [Add the ability to switch the interface on international sites to English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391277/339911)